# Is IBM MQ8 compatible with JBoss EAP 7.0?

Tags: ibm-mq

I am getting following error while trying to use the IBM 8.0 all client jar with Jboss 7.0 EAP. So wondering if JBoss EAP 7.0 supports IBM MQ 8 or not.

```
stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/ibm/mq/ese/jmqi/ESEJMQI.spiConnect(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/ibm/mq/jmqi/system/SpiConnectOptions;Lcom/ibm/mq/jmqi/MQCNO;Lcom/ibm/mq/jmqi/handles/Phconn;Lcom/ibm/mq/jmqi/handles/Pint;Lcom/ibm/mq/jmqi/handles/Pint;)V @63: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'com/ibm/mq/jmqi/system/SpiConnectOptions' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'com/ibm/mq/jmqi/system/LpiPrivConnStruct'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @63
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/ibm/mq/ese/jmqi/ESEJMQI', 'java/lang/String', 'com/ibm/mq/jmqi/system/SpiConnectOptions', 'com/ibm/mq/jmqi/MQCNO', 'com/ibm/mq/jmqi/handles/Phconn', 'com/ibm/mq/jmqi/handles/Pint', 'com/ibm/mq/jmqi/handles/Pint' }
    stack: { 'com/ibm/mq/ese/jmqi/ESEJMQI', 'java/lang/String', 'com/ibm/mq/jmqi/system/SpiConnectOptions', 'com/ibm/mq/jmqi/MQCNO', 'com/ibm/mq/jmqi/handles/Phconn', 'com/ibm/mq/jmqi/handles/Pint', 'com/ibm/mq/jmqi/handles/Pint' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: b200 0399 002b 2a12 0412 5010 06bd 0006
    0x0000010: 5903 2b53 5904 2c53 5905 2d53 5906 1904
    0x0000020: 5359 0719 0553 5908 1906 53b8 0008 2ab4
    0x0000030: 0002 9a00 1f2a 2b2c 2d19 0419 0519 06b7
    0x0000040: 0051 b200 0
```

On the IBM page in Summary section they specifically mentions 7.1 however in Detail section both 7,0 and 7.1

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/which-are-versions-mq-support-jboss-and-weblogic

**Summary -**

- JBoss EAP 7.1 uses Java EE 7.0: it is supported by MQ 8.0 or later

**Details -**
1.b.1) JBoss EAP 7.0 and 7.1 support Java EE 7.0.
These versions of JBoss are supported for MQ 8.0 and later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that your jar names include 'ese' in them which I don't think is usual.

According to [this IBM Support Doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ws-mq-open-session-failing-throwable-aeinvokeservice-sterling-b2b-integrator), one cause of this could be that "MQ jars are corrupted, containing some fragments of MQ ESE (extended security edition)."

It suggests uninstalling the MQ jars and reinstalling from a fresh and certain starting point.

If this is not your cause, could you please update your question to show your Extended Security Edition (ESE) setup? Are you attempting to use ESE?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It worked after updating jars on JBOSS server.